# Terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range aborted error

Tags: c++, outofrangeexception

I'm trying to make a program that turns a string into a char array. My code looks something just like this (this is just a part of my code):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string Word;
    cout << "Type A String And I'll Turn It Into A Char Array ' : ";
    cin >> Word;
    int Length = Word.length();
    char Char_Word[Length];
    //Looping To Set The String Characters To A Char Array
    for (int CharSet = 0; CharSet <= Length; CharSet++)
    {
        Char_Word[CharSet] = Word.at(CharSet);
    }
}
```

But when I run this code and give it an input it outputs this statement

> terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: basic_string
> Aborted

[image: ERROR]

Idk why this happens. Pls help me fix it, and thanks ya for reading it.

Comment: `for (int CharSet = 0; CharSet <= Length; CharSet++)` - how many indices will this loop access? Might it be off by one?

Comment: @churill depends on the length of string.

Comment: Let me narrow it further: `CharSet <= Length`.

Comment: @Agent_A Just in case the penny hasn't dropped `for (int CharSet = 0; CharSet < Length; CharSet++)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are writing out of the range of char_word variable.

```
//First make enough space for char_word
int length = word.length()+1;
char Char_word[ length ];
for( int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
     Char_word[i] = word.at(i);
Char_word[length-1] = '\0'; //very important
```

Reading or writing beyond the range is a bad thing in C/C++. It's a good point a hacker can exploit to make ill your program...
NB: I didn't test it... I wrote directly from my phone

Comment: `char Char_word[ length ];` is no valid C++, but a compiler specific extension. Also the whole "copy `std::string` to char array" is kind of pointless, because `std::string` _is_ a char array. And the loop is also off by one, just in the other direction.

Comment: I tested the code on the online compiler wandbox.org works fine std::string word ="testing123";  
//First make enough space for char_word
int length = word.length()+1;
char Char_word[ length ];
for( int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
     Char_word[i] = word.at(i);
Char_word[length-1] = '\0';
std::cout << Char_word << "\n";

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard (the loop is right though, but a bit confusing)

Answer (score 1):

There are some mistakes in your code:

- you are using a variable length array, which is [not standard C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/). Dynamic arrays need to be allocated with `new[]` (or better, by a `std::vector`).
- your loop is going out of bounds of the `std::string`. The `at()` method performs bounds checking, throwing a `std::out_of_range` exception for indexes >= `size()`. Your loop condition needs to use `<` instead of `<=`.

Try this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string Word;
    cout << "Type A String And I'll Turn It Into A Char Array ' : ";
    cin >> Word;
    size_t Length = Word.length();
    char *Char_Word = new char[Length+1];
    //Looping To Set The String Characters To A Char Array
    for (size_t CharSet = 0; CharSet < Length; CharSet++)
    {
        Char_Word[CharSet] = Word[CharSet];
    }
    Char_Word[Length] = '\0';
    // use Char_Word as needed...
    delete[] Char_Word;
}
```

However, that said, `std::string` is already a `char[]` array. You can get a pointer to a string’s underlying array using the string’s `c_str()` or `data()` method.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string Word;
    cout << "Type A String And I'll Turn It Into A Char Array ' : ";
    cin >> Word;
    const char *Char_Word = Word.c_str();
    // use Char_Word as needed...
}
```